# Min Max in Combine on an Array

Tags: combine

Given, I have

```
let minMaxPublisher = [[10,-19,100,-34],[-100,3,2,11],[100,200,-101]].publisher
```

how would you get the min max of the whole thing?

Comment: What do you consider "min max of the whole thing". Should it be treated as a flat list of numbers, or the min max of the sum of the nested arrays... please be specific

Comment: Ma man, with that answer its not possible to help you, sorry.

Comment: Yes. It should be treated as a flat list of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like:

```
import Combine

let minMaxPublisher = [[10,-19,100,-34],[-100,3,2,11],[100,200,-101]].publisher
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .min()
    .sink {
        print("Min is \($0)")
    }
```

The first `.publisher` publishes a sequence of arrays.  Each of those is passed through `flatMap` where each individual array itself is converted to a sequence and each of those subsequences is passed out of `flatMap` one at a time.  Then you get the `min` of that sequence and print it.